# React Hook is called in function which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

My `blog.js` component :

```
import {useStaticQuery, graphql} from "gatsby"


const blog = () => {
    const {site} = useStaticQuery(
        graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    `
    )
    return site.siteMetadata
}

export default blog
```

Gatsby docs : https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/

I've tried to fixed this issue !!

have any solution ??

> Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Capitalise the name of your component:

```
import {useStaticQuery, graphql} from "gatsby"


const Blog = () => {
  const {site} = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
  return site.siteMetadata
}

export default Blog
```

[User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

Comment: Not working !! It's working , when i use `StaticQuery` . https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/

Comment: Are you able to provide more information as to exactly what's not working?